# Class Design in C++ program

Tags: c++, class, oop, class-design

I'm currently working on a little project in C++. I'm fairly new to C++/Programming and wanted to ask how my classes should be designed.

To be specific: I want to write a little program for chatting. Just simple communication between two programs/computers. For that I want to use a good class design because, although it is only a small project (just for the sake of learning), I want it to be well designed and extensible.

My program should have about 5 classes (`Handlers` etc, the `Updater` and `App` - the main class only for this program).

I'll give you a few examples of ideas I have how I could design one part of the program. The first part should be the connection part (handled by `Connection`). The task is to build up a connection between the two programs. It will also set up local files, which will hold the information to print, and connect it to the 'server' file. Later in the program there should be access to the `File_Handler` class so it can edit/read the local file and read/request to write to the 'server' file. (How exactly it's gonna do it is already figured out, so as long as it is not necessary I'd like to keep this system as it is ;) ). But now let's get to the ideas I have:

#### Idea 1

`App` creates an instance of `Connection` to set up the connection.

`Connection` then creates an instance of `File_Handler` which will set up the files (in this case `File_Hanlder` would hold the paths with static variables) and then destroy that instance because it is no longer needed by `Connection`.

Another class (instance is held by `App`) then creats an own instance of `File_Hanlder` later and could work with the files since the variable for the path is static.

#### Idea 2

`App` creates an Instance of `Connection` and `File_Handler` (lets call them `con` and `fil`).

To set up the connection, `fil` is passed per reference to `con` to set up the variable paths for the files and create the files etc. .

For working with the files later, `App` would pass around `fil` to manage all the file handling for the other classes which would, for example, update the chat etc.

That would require a lot of classes to have a constructor or (a) function(s) which needs to have a `File_Handler` parameter and the same variable would be passed around a lot of times.

#### Idea 3

The last idea I have is that `Connection`, `File_Handler` and the other `classes` would be created very general without any or near to zero relation to other classes.

`App` then creates a lot of functions (or even 'subclasses') to work with these classes almost like working with Frameworks which were developed independently and thus could, theoraticly, be used in another program without any problems.

---

Which solution do you think would be the best? Or is there another solution you have for me which would be even better?

Comment: Just a side note. 1) C++ is not Java; some say that it isn't even an OOP language. For a program in C++ to be *well designed and extensible* it doesn't have to consist of classes at all. For many tasks, a bunch of free functions would be better. Classes are good, but they lead to awful design when are used improperly. 2) You said that you are new to C++. I recommend you to learn more about C++ itself, and only after you feel good with the language you can proceed to thinking about things like program architecture. Doing this at the beginning can lead to bad habits.

Comment: Just a couple questions regarding how this should best be answered. 
1. Are you ever going to be multi-threading this?
2. When you say "best" what do you mean? Is it the smallest code base; the most reusable code base; cross platform; fastest executing; etc. 
3. Is this a homework assignment? If it isn't I apologize, but it looks like one. If it IS a homework assignment, I would speak with your instructor regarding what he/she desires from you for the assignment and then come back here should you run into specific problems.

Comment: @lisyarus Very well said; Aemmel Don't worry about your code being perfect when your just starting out. Just work on learning the language; and if you right spaghetti code, then don't fret. Most of us have probably written spaghetti code at some point.

Comment: @lisyarus quick side note: just looked up the word 'fairly' (im german) and I didn't mean very new, I've been programming in C++ for almost 2 years now but with very long brakes in between. The biggest being 6 months.  But thanks for the advice with the free functions, the first book I read about C++ only used classes, no free functions what so ever so I kinda wanted to do everything with classes as well. But that acutally solves some of my problems :) (btw: what do you think would be the best solution to my answer? still interested :D)

Comment: @Aemmel quick search for synonyms got "quite, pretty, rather, enough". I agree, this does not mean "very new", but for me it means that you are still not very used to the language.

Comment: @Rootix Multithreading isn't planned, no. 2. I mean the way that would be the most extensible and reusable. 3. No. Why do you think it would be? Am I that boring?..

Comment: @Aemmel 1. Probably good not to multithread the application if you are still learning. (You generally don't do it at the beginning regardless, but sometimes that decision can help with how you decide to design it.) 2. Sounds good. 3. Just how you worded it, it looked like a homework question in how it was phrased. Nothing wrong with that, its just often times they require different answers because they have to utilize certain "aspects" of programming. (E.G. Can't use STL, must use c-style functions, etc.)

Comment: @Aemmel As for what options you should do, this is highly opinionated. First, I would completely remove the "App" class. Run everything from the free-function main. As lisyarus commented, having main enclosed in a class isn't often used in c++. (Some compilers won't even let you do it; and I am not 100% sure what standard says regarding it. This being said, I would highly recommend going with option 3, this is how I often structure my code with the individual project implementing previous classes from prior projects through custom functions and classes. Especially on stuff like file-management

Comment: @Rootix I of course wouldn't include main() in App! I would write functions for the flow of the program in App and then execute this code from main() (which would be free in the main.cpp file).    And thanks for the tip, I'll try it this way probably combined with way 1 for the rest of the program.

Comment: This is extremely opinion-based and thus not the kind of question appropriate for Stackoverflow. In any case, keep in mind that OOP is only a tool. You can write perfectly well-designed and extensible software without a single virtual function - just look at the standard-library containers/algorithms/iterators! If you really want to learn OOP, you need a motivating example where run-time polymorphism simplifies your solution instead of complicating it.

Comment: As for your question, *"Which solution do you think would be the best?"*, this depends on too many factors to even remotely give you a good answer. I'd say try all of them and make your own observations. What difficulties will you encounter? What will work and what won't work? You just have to go through a lot of different good and bad designs to become a proficient software developer.

Comment: However, here's one hard technical fact: in standard C++, `main` **cannot** be a member function. It has to be `int main()` (or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`). No class, no namespace.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I actually really like your answer, thank you very much. And to main(): like I said, my int main() {} would be in the main.cpp file in no class, no namespace, no what so ever, I already know that :)